# What's our policy on dead links?

Tags: discussion, links

Every so often I stumbled on some old answer with a dead link.  My OCD kicks in and I want to fix it.  Sometimes I can find an [Internet Archive](http://archive.org) version of the page; other times what appears to be the page has moved within the linked site.  The Internet Archive does not seem to change the answer substantially, but that may not be the case with other fixes.

Should I attempt to fix the broken link or not?

Comment: I have the same OCD! I don't edit enough here to know policy, but on Gardening and Landscaping I was told that fixing links is an improvement like any other edit, and helps the community. The post is missing important information, and if you've seen it, others have, or will. SA relies heavily on links, so I think it's kind of you to take the time. If it's a really low quality post I don't want to bring forward, I leave a comment on it instead, but you have much more experience than I, so your judgement is better! Thanks for caring. If it was my post, I'd appreciate your help!

Comment: Many of the answers here on cooking.sx, are not as perishable as supermarket produce. The answers are still relevant, but the links may be rotten. So my inclination is to fix them. I will try to do as @Preston Fitzgerald suggests and leave a comment to the answer instead of just on the edit comment.

Answer (score 7):

Fix it!

I usually leave a comment to the effect of "It looks like your link died. I tried to replace it but you might want to check to make sure the new one points to the right place."

An archive link is good. A link to a similar but different resource often works just as well.